# Need help in finding recurrance relation

Tags: dynamic-programming

You are very happy because you advanced to the next round of a very important programming contest. You want your best friend to know how happy you are. Therefore, you are going to send him a lot of smile emoticons. You are given an int smiles: the exact number of emoticons you want to send.

You have already typed one emoticon into the chat. Then, you realized that typing is slow. Instead, you will produce the remaining emoticons using copy, paste, and possibly some deleting.

You can only do three different operations:

- Copy all the emoticons you currently have into the clipboard.
- Paste all emoticons from the clipboard.
- Delete one emoticon from the message.

Each operation takes precisely one second. Copying replaces the old content of the clipboard. Pasting does not empty the clipboard. You are not allowed to copy just a part of the emoticons you already have. You are not allowed to delete an emoticon from the clipboard.

Return the smallest number of seconds in which you can turn the one initial emoticon into smiles emoticons.

How to find the recurrence relation for this problem?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It seems that this question, minus the last sentence, is pasted from somewhere. Can you give us the background? Is it perhaps a homework assignment? We like to see people try, as it is the best way to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code and add seconds according to output of this program. A error of infinite loop may be occur correct it.

```
/*  Input :   95 Output : 64,16,8,4,2,1
    Input :   69 Output : 64,4,1
    Input :  277 Output : 256,16,4,1 
    Input :    4 Output : 4
    Input :    1 Output : 1
    Input : 1042 Output : 1024,16,2
*/ 
import java.util.Scanner;
class Emotions
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter no. of Emotions : ");
        int emo = a.nextInt();
        value(emo);
    }
    public static void value(int x)
    {   
        int emo = x;
        int n = 1;  
        do {
        n = n * 2;
        }while(emo > n);
        n = n/2;
        System.out.println(n);
        while((emo - n) != 1)
        {
            value(emo-n);
        }   
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you, please, describe the answer.